# Problema con la creacion de un grafico de nube de palabras (PHP tag Cloud)

Tags: php, foreach

He estado intentando crear una nube de palabras para recopilar las palabras que más han sido utilizadas y que estas resalten más, lo hago mediante un arreglo. El problema es que al imprimir las palabras en el grafico, solo me imprime una palabra y no todas las palabras que estan en el arreglo.

El código que utilice es el siguiente

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
</style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/wordCloud.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->

<?php

$texto = "Muchas javascript por el trabajo realizado y java la java. Profesionales, eficientes, java y flexibles en las javascript, son las necesidades javascript eficientes java a java gran java, necesidades";

$str = str_replace( ',', '', $texto);

$combiertearray = explode (" ", $str);

$muestra = array_count_values($combiertearray);
foreach ($muestra as $key => $value)
{

if ($value > 0)
echo $resultado = "{ 'tag':"."'".$key."'".",'count':"."'".$value."'"." },";
?>


<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloud);
chart.fontFamily = "Courier New";
var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloudSeries());
series.randomness = 0.1;
series.rotationThreshold = 0.5;

series.data = [ 

<?php echo $resultado;?>


];

series.dataFields.word = "tag";
series.dataFields.value = "count";

series.heatRules.push({
 "target": series.labels.template,
 "property": "fill",
 "min": am4core.color("#0000CC"),
 "max": am4core.color("#CC00CC"),
 "dataField": "value"
});

series.labels.template.url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{word}";
series.labels.template.urlTarget = "_blank";
series.labels.template.tooltipText = "{word}: {value}";

var hoverState = series.labels.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");

var subtitle = chart.titles.create();
subtitle.text = "(click to open)";

var title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "Nube de palabras";
title.fontSize = 20;
title.fontWeight = "800";

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>



<?php
}
?>


<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
amCharts
```

Y el resultado que tengo es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, en el arreglo trae todas las palabras escritas, pero a la hora de ponerlo en la gráfica solo imprme una palabra y no se porque si el echo esta dentro del foreach.

Comment: el valor no es numérico estas pasando un string, antes de esto; `if ($value > 0)` debes poner esto `$value= (int) $value;`

Comment: intenato y me dices que te sale.

Comment: fijate que me sale exactamente lo mismo:(

Comment: no puede ser...

Comment: estas seguro???

Comment: por que usas array_count_value???

Comment: ese array_count_value donde iria?

Comment: no hace nada en realidad... no se dime tu para que lo usas???

Comment: Se supone que con eso cuento las palabras que se repiten, para luego ponerlas en la grafica (porque se supone que la grafica de nube mostraria en grandes las palabras mas usadas y en pequeño las que menos se usan).